# Interpreting snort log

Tags: snort

I am new to snort, and I have run snort through a .cap file and got the logs that i should interpret. If a take for instance a block of log like the one below:

```
[**] [1:2463:7] EXPLOIT IGMP IGAP message overflow attempt [**]
[Classification: Attempted Administrator Privilege Gain] [Priority: 1] 
05/29-19:44:02.238185 249.94.153.251 -> 249.94.153.77
IGMP TTL:255 TOS:0x0 ID:9744 IpLen:20 DgmLen:502 MF
Frag Offset: 0x1FFF   Frag Size: 0x01E2
[Xref => http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2004-0367][Xref => http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2004-0176][Xref => http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/9952]
```

I can say that it's an Denial of Service attempt alert, but what do the other information mean ? Could you help me please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about network administration, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets see first is the message that is displayed when snort rule matches the packet. Then classification is also part of that rule and its just for better description. Priority 1 is high 2 is medium and 3 is low. Then you have packet description time, source ip, destination ip, protocol, ttl and so on. Last xref is reference on the attack from mitre database which contains known vulnerabilities. All of these parameters can be part of snort rules. Check snort manual for writing rules for better understanding.